# Knockout.js Initialization using jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using Knockout for the first time, It looks extremely easy but I'm not able to do some simple things which can be done.

My HTML File

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: LOBModel">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:lob_ID"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: lob_Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: lob_Description"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

My JS File

```
    $(window).load(function () {
    getLOB();
    //var vm = {
    //    LOBModel: [
    //       { lob_ID: 'Bert', lob_Name: 'Bertington', lob_Description: 'Bertington' },
    //       { lob_ID: 'Charles', lob_Name: 'Charlesforth', lob_Description: 'Bertington'},
    //       { lob_ID: 'Denise', lob_Name: 'Dentiste', lob_Description: 'Bertington' }
    //    ]
    //}
    //ko.applyBindings(vm);
    //Commented Section Work

    function getLOB() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Admin/GetLOB',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (returndata) {
                alert(returndata.data);
                var LOBModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(returndata);
                ko.applyBindings();
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In my Controller I'm passing the data as follows

```
    public JsonResult GetLob()
    {
        SLADAL objDal = new SLADAL();
        return Json(objDal.GetLOB());
    }
```

Please help.

I'm getting

0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to parse bindings.

Message: TypeError: 'LOBModel' is undefined;

Bindings value: foreach: LOBModel

**EDIT:**
For those who are looking for a complete Ajax Get and Post Example using JSON Array of object, this is a useful link i've found. hope this helps some body.

URL : http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=847

Keep Coding :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind your data to the viewmodel you'll first have to pass it as an argument to the binding method (I'm guessing the LOBModel is an array), like this:

```
            var LOBModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(returndata);
            ko.applyBindings(LOBModel);
```

Then when you access it later on in the html you'll have to use the `$root` keyword.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text:lob_ID"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: lob_Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: lob_Description"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

For more great examples you could always take the interactive tutorial at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/

If you want to add more functionality to your viewmodel you could always create it like this:

```
            var LOBModel = ko.mapping.fromJS({
               data: returndata,
               yourFunctionHere: function () {
                   ...
               }
            });
            ko.applyBindings(LOBModel);
```

Then you'll have to modify your HTML to look like, I've also added the click event as an example of how to access the viewmodel from within a knockout context:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.data">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: lob_ID, click: $root.yourFunctionHere"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: lob_Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: lob_Description"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Just to add more information my json is in this format
[0] => { lob_ID : "dummy" ,lob_Name : "dummy",lob_Description "dummy"}
[1] => { and so on } how will my model understand that it has 3 child elements

Comment: @RonakJain the mapping plugin takes care of that for you. It will turn your array into a viewmodel, but I would suspect that you would want to add other info to the viewmodel as well? then you could extend a JavaScript object with the resulting from your web service and later on attach more functions to it... I'll add an example of that in the answer.

Comment: When I create a Hard-Coded Json and use it in my Javascript file, it works just fine ( Mentioned in the commented section). but when I use Ajax call to return an Array of Object ( Class Object) it only returns key i.e, [0],[1],[2], etc and value as LOB_ID and LOB_Name and Lob_Description. I'm not sure how does the mapping works, but the code is facing some binding issue, though seems to be very naive

Comment: @RonakJain If your not going to change the data that you receive from the server then it's unnecessary to map it via the plugin. Then you could just add it to the viewmodel directly. `ko.applyBindings(returndata);`

Comment: Though It didn't solve my problem, you directed me in the right way to solve the issue. Thanks mate.